How to handle a situation where I informed my supervisor, did not get a response, continued with the project, got reprimanded
I have a main job where I have defined duties that must get done, and an understanding that additional time may be spent on activities that align with the organizations goals. The difficulty is that I am also technically an hourly worker although I do not have a time sheet - we are expected to work 40 hours/week, but do not account for this time in any way. This is...another issue that is definitely weird, but here we are.
I always make sure to finish my required, defined duties or, if that is not possible (say because I am waiting on a contractor to get something done) I will make sure that I prepare ahead if I can. However, I find myself having about 10 hours per week of time where my assigned duties are complete, and I have taken to using that time to work on activities that align with organizational goals.
Or so I thought. These additional duties are, essentially, automating certain bothersome job duties that are easy to automate. The issue is that once I had completed automating stuff for my department, I started working on automating stuff for other departments. This is bothering my supervisor because he believes that I should be using this extra time only for work in our department, and has reprimanded me, claiming that he can no longer account for my time nor justify my spending it on non-departmental work. He very explicitly told me that he was unaware that any of this was going on.
The problem is that I did inform him, via email. I wrote reports about what I was doing. I have an email trail that specifically mentions my work with other departments. However, he did not respond to any of these when they were sent.
Now, I believe one of the issues is that I took non-response for consent. Clearly this was not what was intended. But I was also reprimanded for not informing him when I actually did. So how can I navigate this? The work environment is pretty tense right now because I honestly have no clue what I'm supposed to be doing with my additional time.

So you had completed everything required of you for your own department before helping others, and if you hadn't helped them you'd have been left idle? That sucks in any case, but it sucks way more to get dinged for it. But that's often big company culture - managers are more concerned about whose budget you're working off than the overall good of the organisation.

Politely ask for sit-down via email.
In the email explain that you thought you were doing what was expected of you and you now understand that was not the case. "My goal in asking for the meeting is to ensure that I don't make this same type of mistake." Then ask for boundries.
Make the email into your own words.
Don't argue during the meeting. The goal is how to move forward and build the manager's trust.
This is a simple case of "even if you are right, you are still wrong". It sucks but it happens. The manager didn't communicate well and dinged you for it. By you reaching out, you can rebuild the trust. Even if it wasn't you that negatively affected the trust, it should be rebuilt.

The best way to rebuild trust would be for the manager to acknowledge that he was repeatedly informed of the true facts (so the OP says), and to acknowledge that he has made a mistake with his complaint. I don't see how it rebuilds anyone's trust for the OP to proceed on the premise that it was in fact his own mistake, when there is no evidence of any error on his part. It will only ratify the manager's misperception.

@Steve Nobody ever said that life was fair. This isn't an even relationship between the OP and the manager. The Manager didn't respond but didn't cause the situation. Could have prevented it - YES. It was a classic multi-step failure AND someone being punished for being proactive. Is it BS? Sure it is. Is the manager being short-sighted here? Absolutely. At the end of the day, Who's trust of whom matters? The manager's of OP. Fix that or move on to another company. But don't start a fight because life should be fair. It isn't.

@Steve: You can't make people see things your way. At best, you can openly disagree with them and hope they re-evaluate their own stance because of it. But when you're in a power imbalance, you would be doing so at the risk of any positive reputation you would have with your direct superior, which comes at a cost when it fails. You're right about what would happen in an ideal world. But that's not necessarily indicative of what will happen to OP if they pursue this.

@Flater, it doesn't necessarily sound like the OP needs to pursue the issue, or that the "reprimand" was of a formal nature, rather than just an expression of annoyance on the spot. And the annoyance may not be hugely directed at the OP, but merely at the fact that some competing department has been assisted to improve their efficiency - a devious and calculating manager may not want to say this out loud, probably hence the reason why it occurred in the first place. (1/2)

My point is that there seems to be no reason for the OP to accept wrongdoing when there has seemingly been none, and I think this answer is counselling dishonesty and corrupt behaviour. I don't see how your reputation improves by admitting false charges, or that trust is improved that way, unless the manager is so crooked that his trust will improve by having a little wrongdoer beneath him, or that the OP's trust will be improved by working in an environment where false charges can be levied at any moment and you are expected to admit to them. (2/2)

@Steve Failing to accept that you may have made mistakes, even though you weren't aware at the time that they were a mistake; is not good. OP's post is susceptible to their own bias. Regardless of whether they may have been told otherwise in the past or not, they are now explicitly being told that they should not be doing this. The best way to defuse this is to acknowledge, apologise on the assumption you misunderstood, and move on. If you want to die on this hill and butt heads with management, you do you, but your "counseling dishonesty and corrupt behavior" remark is severely misguided.

@Steve "My point is that there seems to be no reason for the OP to accept wrongdoing when there has seemingly been none" is encouraging self-destructive behavior. It is like saying, "I had the right-of-way" but not stopping for the truck coming straight at you.

@DogBoy37, there are a lot of potential ways to respond to a truck coming, but allowing a truck to actually hit you, and then accepting responsibility for the "accident" lest the driver get even more angry and attack you more fiercely, is not really amongst the common ones.

@Steve Please take this with a grain of salt. Really more of an explaination of my thinking that I've learned the hard way and hope to help others avoid the same pitfalls that I've experienced. My personal definition of being an adult is when you are presented with a situation and all the choices suck. With this understanding, there is no way the OP can do anything but take it and move on. Understanding that the manager sees as a loss of trust is important because OP can address that. Change the managers mind - lost cause and waste of time. I've been there, done that. Be right or be smart.

@Steve To learn not to respond when being baited. Who are you to question my moral fiber? Have you every had to make payroll? How many peoples lives are you responsible for? I hear crickets.

@DogBoy37, ah so you're talking as an employer, counselling workers that they should accept your false allegations whenever you wish to make them, or else?

@Steve I am talking as someone that has eaten more crap from more people in my career than a troll like you can imagine. Both from my bosses in the past and clients. On the flip side, I encourage my team members to call me on it when (no if) I foo bar something. That is how I have people that have been with me over 30 years. BTW. This is my last response to you. I try very hard to be polite to everyone and talk to them online as I would to their faces. Try it someone. It is what growing up feels like.

I don't think its justifiable to work for other departments. If the company is large enough then there are transferrable costs between departments. If it isn't then your manager woukd probably have done some horse trading or at least received "I owe you one" from the other departments manager.
Knock on the managers door if possible and request a few minutes of their time. Apologise for your mistake, do point out that you had thought that informing by email was enough and ask for some direction and ask what not to do in the future.

I think your first sentence is way off. There are companies that think like that but most do not. Reprimanding an employee for doing work that benefits the company as a whole but not their particular department is a bad business decision. It happens but it fortunately is not universal. Your second paragraph is a useful answer to OPs question.

Just take the reprimand and move on.
Proving to your boss they were wrong won't help you.  Documenting your rightness won't help you.  Sometimes you get in trouble over things you shouldn't have gotten in trouble over.  Just move on.
If your supervisor is too hard to work for, find new employment.  There is no winning a fight with your boss, only degrees of losing.
